# Yii2 Kartik connect Select2 and SortableInput

Tags: yii2, jquery-select2, kartik-v

I'm using the [select2](http://demos.krajee.com/widget-details/select2) and [sortableinput](http://demos.krajee.com/sortable-input) widget from kartik. I want to select something with select2 and have the selected element in the sortableinput widget. I was wondering how i can achieve this. Only with js? or do i have to use ajax/pjax? Since i'm new to this topic, some help where to start would be really cool.

bye.

**EDIT:**

The Select2 uses ajax and [mapquestapi](https://developer.mapquest.com) to search for the address. If the found address is selected, the data should be put into the sortable-input field. So a list of addresses can be made. Within the sortable-input, it will be possible to sort the addresses. For a prototype see the image and the basic code below.

[image: The view for the input]

```
use kartik\select2\Select2;
use kartik\sortinput\SortableInput;

$ajaxJs = <<< JS
function(data) {
    console.log(data.params.data);
    // put here code for logic?
}
JS;    

echo Select2::widget([
    'name' => 'kv-repo-template',
    'value' => '14719648',
    'initValueText' => 'Adresse suchen ...',
    'options' => ['placeholder' => 'Search for a repo ...'],
    'pluginOptions' => [
        'allowClear' => true,
        'minimumInputLength' => 1,
        'ajax' => [
            'url' => "http://www.mapquestapi.com/geocoding/v1/address?key=key_here",
            'dataType' => 'json',
            'delay' => 250,
            //'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {q:params.term, page: params.page}; }'),
            'data' => new JsExpression('function(params) { return {street:params.term, state:"Upper Austria", thumbMaps:false}; }'),
            'processResults' => new JsExpression($resultsJs),
            'cache' => true
        ],
        'escapeMarkup' => new JsExpression('function (markup) { return markup; }'),
        'templateResult' => new JsExpression('formatRepo'),
        'templateSelection' => new JsExpression('formatRepoSelection'),
    ],
    'pluginEvents' => [
        "select2:select" => new JsExpression($ajaxJs),
    ],
]);

   $form->field($model, 'sort_list')->label(false)->widget(SortableInput::classname(), [
'items' => [
    1 => ['content' => 'Adress #1'],
    2 => ['content' => 'Adress #2'],
    3 => ['content' => 'Adress #3'],
],
'hideInput' => true,
'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => true]]);
```

**EDIT 2:**

Thanks for @MuhammadOmerAslam i changed the code. So now the entries will be put into the sortableinput list. Unfortunately i can't drag and drop the new entries. Do i have to reinitialize the sortableinput list?

```
$ajaxJs = <<< JS
function(data) {
    console.log(data.params.data);
    doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<li data-key="' + (document.querySelector('.sortable').childElementCount + 1) + '"role="option" aria-grabbed="false" draggable="true">' + data.params.data.street + '</li>', "text/html").body.firstChild;
    document.querySelector('.sortable').appendChild(doc);
}
JS;
```

**EDIT 3:**

Get the sortable and call sortable(); `$('#address-sortable').sortable();`

```
$ajaxJs = <<< JS
function(data) {
    doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString('<li data-key="' + (document.querySelector('.sortable').childElementCount + 1) + '"role="option" aria-grabbed="false" draggable="true">' + data.params.data.street + '</li>', "text/html").body.firstChild;
    document.querySelector('.sortable').appendChild(doc);
    $('#address-sortable').sortable();
}
JS;
```

and set the id for the sortableinput list:

```
$form->field($model, 'sort_list')->label(false)->widget(SortableInput::classname(), [
    'items' => [
        1 => ['content' => 'Adress #1'],
        2 => ['content' => 'Adress #2'],
        3 => ['content' => 'Adress #3'],
    ],
    'hideInput' => false,
    'options' => ['class' => 'form-control', 'readonly' => true, 'id'=>'address']
]);
```

Comment: can you add more description as in by selecting the option from the `select2` do you want the similar option to be `dragged` or `re-arranged` or just `selected/highlighted`.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for your comment. I updated my question. Should be more clear now.

Comment: ok so you want that which ever address you click on should be added as a new element inthe sortable input list ? if that is correct then i see that you are using the `select2:select` event and passing some javascript in the php var `$ajaxJs` can you show what are you currently doing when you select an address?

Comment: sorry the javascript is on the top, i didnt saw it earlier ignore the last part of my previous comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by using `javascript`  inside the `select:select` event for the `select2`.

For adding a new item in the sortable list you can use the `DOMParser().parseFromString` to add the `html` for the new item (`li`), i assume the html nodes are like `<li class="p1 mb1 blue bg-white">Address content</li>` and then use `querySelector().appendChild()` to add it to the `.js-sortable-buttons` container.

You should update the `javascript` block on the top of your view to the following.

```
$ajaxJs = <<< JS
function(e) {
    doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(`<li class="p1 mb1 blue bg-white">${e.currentTarget.options[e.currentTarget.options.selectedIndex].text}</li>`, "text/html").body.firstChild;
    document.querySelector('.js-sortable-buttons').appendChild(doc);
}
JS;
```

For more examples you can visit [**`html5sortable`**](https://lukasoppermann.github.io/html5sortable/index.html) examples which is the base for the `yii2-sortable`.

Comment: yes you need to initialize the `sortable` by calling the `sortable('.js-sortable-buttons');`, i provided the link (**html5sortable**) in my answer where you can add the sortable items on runtime and re-init them i thought you would go through it  @Luc ,

Comment: thanks for the reply. I read the link, but didn't quite understood how to actually call the sortable. I updated my question with the solution. So i have to get the list and call sortable: $('#address-sortable').sortable(); not quite the same as you suggested, but it works.